# Start Activity from service for API Level < 10

Tags: android, service, android-activity, permissions

In an attempt to find a way to start an activity from my background service (same package), I am stuck in level 10 API or less (trying in 2.3.3) where it keeps complaining for permission STATUS_BAR which is a system permission.

I have tried various methods with no success.

The activity definition in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.company.app.ui.ViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.app.action.START_VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:pathPattern="com.company.app"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code:

```
Intent it = new Intent("com.company.app.action.START_VIEW");
it.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ViewActivity.class.getName()));
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
```

Alternative:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Both fail with the exception:

```
03-16 14:10:07.583: E/MyApp(367): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.company.app.action.START_DDM flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.company.app/.ViewActivity } from ProcessRecord{43db3d88 367:com.company.app/10029} (pid=367, uid=10029) requires android.permission.STATUS_BAR
03-16 14:10:07.703: E/MyApp(367): android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)
03-16 14:10:07.793: E/MyApp(367): android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)
03-16 14:10:07.864: E/MyApp(367): android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1214)
03-16 14:10:07.944: E/MyApp(367): android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
03-16 14:10:08.044: E/MyApp(367): android.app.ApplicationContext.startActivity(ApplicationContext.java:555)
03-16 14:10:08.174: E/MyApp(367): android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:248)
03-16 14:10:08.244: E/MyApp(367): com.company.app.service.MyService.showHideView(MyService.java:616)
03-16 14:10:08.324: E/MyApp(367): com.company.app.service.MyServiceThread$1.handleMessage(MyServiceThread.java:99)
03-16 14:10:08.394: E/MyApp(367): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 14:10:08.473: E/MyApp(367): com.company.app.service.MyServiceThread.callShowHideView(MyServiceThread.java:231)
03-16 14:10:08.563: E/MyApp(367): com.company.app.service.MyServiceThread.run(MyServiceThread.java:205)
```

**Update: Posted solution below... thank you Android for the stupid error message!**

Comment: we really need that blah blah blah, to identify your problem

Comment: please post the full logcat..

Comment: Added full exception trace as requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling all day on this, found the solution:

Gingerbread, remove

```
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
```

in manifest and it works.

:(

Answer (score 0):

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

add this and check it.

Comment: Only implicit intent require this, he uses an explicit intent.

Comment: I had this in the past. Do difference.